# blocking a normal user's access to a command using sudoers file

Tags: permissions, sudo

I want to block a normal user from using a command, in sudoers file. I don't want the user to be able to use sudo at all.
I tried editing sudoers file like this:

```
student ALL=/usr/bin/*, !/usr/bin/pwd
```

This doesn't seem to work, since the user has access to pwd command.Though, he doesn't have access to pwd command using sudo ( while having access to all other commands using sudo ). What I want, is for the user to be restricted to use sudo, and to be restricted from using the pwd command.
Can this be done with sudoers file?

Thanks.

Comment: Most shells provide `pwd` as a shell builtin

Comment: So this means I can't block a user from using it ? what about other commands like "reboot" ?

Comment: Also the sudoers file can not  block commands not run with `sudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose this a final answer :

Also the sudoers file can not block commands not run with sudo – Soren A

Thanks.